# Question about expression: a ? b : c

Tags: c#

I tried to use the following example codes by using a ? b : c expression:

```
DateTime? GetValue(string input)
{
  DateTime? val = string.IsNullOrEmpty(input) ? null : DateTime.Parse(input);
  return val;
}
```

I got compiling error since in the a ? b : c expression because b and c are different data types; Not sure if I can use (DateTime?) case to c part?

```
  DateTime? val = string.IsNullOrEmpty(input) ? null : (DateTime?) DateTime.Parse(input);
```

I would rather not use if to split this one into two or three statement.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
return string.IsNullOrEmpty(input) ? (DateTime?)null : DateTime.Parse(input);
//or
return string.IsNullOrEmpty(input) ? null : (DateTime?)DateTime.Parse(input);
```

Either works, you have to provide some means of compatability between the two types, since DateTime cannot be null, you need to explicitly with one that you're trying to go to `DateTime?`, then the compiler can implicit cast the other.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler is ensuring that b and c in your a ? b: c are of the same type. In your original example c is a DateTime (since DateTime.Parse returns a DateTime), and b can not be a DateTime cause its null, so the compiler says:

> Type of conditional expression cannot
>   be determined because there is no
>   implicit conversion between ''
>   and 'System.DateTime'

You can get it to work (Because there is an implicit convertion from DateTime? to DateTime)

```
 DateTime? val = string.IsNullOrEmpty(input) ? (DateTime?)null : DateTime.Parse(input);
```

But ... I think this is one of those cases where the following is much easier to follow.

```
DateTime? val = null;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input)) {
  val =  DateTime.Parse(input);
}
```

With the caveat that the whole premise of the function is pretty risky, you are only failing early sometimes.

The method has very **odd semantics**! It will fail with an exception if an invalid date format is passed in **unless** it is null or an empty string. This violates the fail early principle.

Comment: it is cleaner than my. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Did you actually try it? Yes it works. Go grab [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) to try little things like this.

> LINQPad is more than just a LINQ tool: it's a highly ergonomic code snippet IDE that instantly executes any C#/VB expression, statement block or program – the ultimate in dynamic development. Put an end to those hundreds of Visual Studio Console projects cluttering your source folder!

Comment: sorry I cannot try it now since I don't have VS available while my friend and me discussed the issue in a cafe shop. Thanks!

Comment: Still recommend LINQPad. Dirty little secret: it'll run off a thumbdrive, and hence will probably run on the internet cafe's computers ;)

Comment: not sure about MacBook Pro. We don't have Windows. It is straight Mac OS. I guess LINQPad is not for Mac OS. Anyway, your recommendation is a new discovery for us. For sure I'll try it when I am back to Windows.

Comment: By the way, I win my bet. My friend insisted it be impossible to use a ? b : c expression and I had to use if statement in this case. Just another fresh cup of big size coffee!

Comment: Maybe you can share it then! For the record though, LINQPad is written in .NET. It should work on OS X, as long as mono is installed, but it probably isn't at an internet cafe. Too bad :(

Answer (score 1):

I just tried

```
public static DateTime? GetValue(string input)
{
    DateTime? val = string.IsNullOrEmpty(input) ? null : (DateTime?)DateTime.Parse(input); 
    return val;
}
```

and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
DateTime? val = string.IsNullOrEmpty(input) ? null : new DateTime?(DateTime.Parse(input));
```

Edit:
The other answers will work too, but with this syntax you won't even need casting.